# c- segmentation fault error due to calling a function that has text that user put in the terminal

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, command-line-arguments, function-declaration

**Summary**

I am trying to pass the text that user has put in the terminal and pass it to the function named printString(). I don't fully understand C but I think I has to do with the pointer not being in the heap. Any help would be appreacitaed!

```
#include <stdio.h>
void printString();
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
        int commandAmount = 1;
        while (commandAmount < argc) {
        printString(commandAmount, &argv);
        }
        return 0;
}
void printString(int commandAmount, char* argv[]) {
        printf("the word is %s," , argv[commandAmount]);
}
```

```
./shortExample example
```

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: `void printString();`? Fix the prototype to have the actual args.

Comment: `while (commandAmount < argc)` Can you explain when/how you see that loop ever ending?

Comment: @kaylum The program crashes. That also ends the loop. ;)

Comment: Thank you @kaylum &Gerhardh for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prototype `void printString();` does not match the actual implementation.
It should have been:

```c
void printString(int commandAmount, char* argv[]);
```

You could also skip the prototype and just implement the function before `main`. Your loop `while (commandAmount < argc)` seems to not have any way to finish since you never increase `commandAmount`. This can cause *undefined behavior* and with such, your program may crash or do just about anything.
I suggest making a `for`-loop to fix that.

Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void printString(int commandAmount, char* argv[]) {
    printf("the word is %s,", argv[commandAmount]);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    for(int commandAmount = 1; commandAmount < argc; ++commandAmount) {
        printString(commandAmount, argv);
    }
}
```

or in the way you structured it:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void printString(int commandAmount, char* argv[]); // corrected

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int commandAmount = 1;
    while (commandAmount < argc) {
        printString(commandAmount, argv);
        ++commandAmount;                           // needed
    }
}

void printString(int commandAmount, char* argv[]) {
    printf("the word is %s,", argv[commandAmount]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation @Ted Lyngmo

Answer (score 2):

For starters this function declaration

```
void printString();
```

does not provide a function prototype. So the compiler determines the type of the parameters of the function from the function call

```
printString(commandAmount, &argv);
```

However the expression `&argv` used in this call

```
printString(commandAmount, &argv);
```

has the type `char ***` due to the declaration of the identifier `argv`

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But the corresponding parameter in the definition of the function `printString` has the type `char **` due to adjusting by the compiler parameters having array types to pointers to array element type.

That is this function declaration

```
void printString(int commandAmount, char* argv[]) {
```

is adjusted by the compiler to

```
void printString(int commandAmount, char** argv) {
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Thus there are incompatible types of the argument expression and of the parameter. As a result this call

```
printf("the word is %s," , argv[commandAmount]);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Moreover this loop in main

```
    int commandAmount = 1;
    while (commandAmount < argc) {
    printString(commandAmount, &argv);
    }
```

in general is an infinite loop because the variable `commandAmount` is not changed within the loop.

Firstly you should provide the function prototype before `main` to make your program more safer

```
void printString(int commandAmount, char** argv);
```

and call the function like

```
printString(commandAmount, argv);
                           ^^^^
```

Of course you need also to change the loop in main.

Pay attention to that as the value of the parameter `commandAmount` is not outputted within the function then in fact it is redundant. You could pass to the function the pointer to the string itself. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printString( const char *s );

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) 
{
    for ( int commandAmount = 1; commandAmount < argc; commandAmount++ ) 
    {
        printString( argv[commandAmount] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}

void printString( const char *s ) 
{
    printf( "the word is %s, " , s );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful explanation. I appreciate it!